# Grab Only Numeric Number from Specific Text Paragraph During Mouseover/Hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, code-analysis

I am having an issue of detecting numbers from a html string paragraph.
Let me start with an overview of the html page.

1. 1 table consisting only numbers
2. 1 paragraph consisting alphabets, numbers and symbols

What I am trying to do is, when user mouseover or hover on any number in the paragraph, the same number in the table will have a change in style (maybe highlighted).

The question is, **how do I extract the number from the paragraph using jQuery by just mouseover or hover?**

I have been thinking of adding span tag to each numeric value in the paragraph so that I can maybe use `$(this).find('span').text(...) to match with the cells of the table afterwards.

Anyone give me some idea how to start the detection? Tqvm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to fetch all numbers from a text and do something with it afterwards.

```
// Set your selector here, because its probably not all 'p' elements
$("p").hover(function(){
    var paragraphText = $(this).text();
    var allNumbers = paragraphText.match( /\d+/g );
    console.log(allNumbers); // A string, comma seperated, with all numbers
    var numbersArray = allNumbers.split(',');
    console.log(numbersArray); // An array of all the numbers

    // Loop through the array and do something with each number.
    $.each(numbersArray, function(index, theNumber){
        console.log(theNumber);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the new info about .match( /\d+/g )!! :D

Comment: can the regex detect both float numbers and integers too? I tried with /^\d+$/ and /(\d+(\.\d+)?)/ but the result is either null/undefined, else detect only numbers of more than 1 character. [-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]* display everything but it doesn't detect anymore..

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tds = $('td');
  
  $('span').on('mouseenter ', function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $.each(tds, function(i, l){
      var tmp = tds.eq(i).text();
      if (tmp == text) {
        tds.eq(i).addClass('highlight');
      } else {
        tds.eq(i).removeClass('highlight');
      }
    });
  });

  $('span').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $.each(tds, function(i, l){
      tds.eq(i).removeClass('highlight');
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.highlight{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>
Lorem <span>1</span> Ipsum <span>2</span> Dolor <span>3</span>
</p>
</p>
```

Comment: omg thank you soooo much! This is one I wanna achieve after inserting spam tags dynamically! :DDD @Horst Jahns